# Magento Catalog Price Rules not working half a day

Tags: php, magento

I’m facing a very very weird problem with Catalog price rules. They work only between 10:00 and 23:00 server time. So if i apply them between this period everything works great, but if i change the rules or reindex after 23:00 all prices will be back to normal. Also if i try to apply a rule outside that period the rule is not applied. I’ve installed Cron Doctor to see if there is any cron that runs at those times and nothing.

I’m running Magento 1.8.1.0.

Any ideas will be appreciated because i’m looking for over 4 days to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone facing this issue, your Default Store Timezone must match your server timezone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cron.php has been scheduled for execution as per Magento recommendation.

Then check if all indexing are run as per crontab settings and all indexing complete there process.

Catalog rules are generally populated in DB table for 3 days so if no cron( Indexing )  has been executed for last three days then probably catalog rules might not be effective.

Comment: Magento cron works perfect. I am able to effectively "Apply Rules" only between the hours mentioned. I will move the site on another hosting to see if there i have the same problems.

Comment: @Alexandru - Were you able to solve it after moving to another hosting?

Comment: Check your server timings and match to your magento timings.

Comment: @win8-learner : yes i've fixed the problem by moving to a VPS where i've set the server timezone to UTC. This way Magento had the correct time. Before moving i've change the timezone from app.php but this method it's not very safe.